# MS Excel (2003) Is there a bug in DSUM or am I missing something blindingly obvious?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to check some data in an Excel database, and have created a separate sheet (in the same workbook) with what should be some fairly simple "DSUM" queries.

I have copied a formula (absolute and relative, as appropriate) which works fine for the first twenty three DSUMs, then just gives a "#value" error.

I'm using a cell reference for the middle "field" value ... which strictly speaking I shouldn't but it works with the first half(ish) of the queries. Just in case, I've also tried text labels in quote marks, and numerical column numbers - still results in an error.

If I repeat the last working query before it starts to error, that works fine. If I delete the working query or change it to be the same as the first non-working one, that errors. The last column in the 'check' sheet that works is 'Z', with 'AA' being the first non-working one. It's most probably just a coincidence but I thought I should mention it.

A copy of the file is here: http://www.s-t-u-f-f.net/eurovision.xls The DSUM queries are on the 'Check' sheet.

If anyone is aware of a bug, I'd be really grateful to know. I've stared at / played with / shouted at the problem for hours. Alternatively, if I've missed something really basic, feel free to point it out and feel the heat from where you are as I turn red.

Comment: I can't find `DSUM` in your workbook. Did you upload the right one?

Comment: Me neither. What criteria are you using?

Comment: @Sean Cheshire Oops ... no! Sorry - well spotted. I uploaded an earlier 'in progress' copy and foolishly didn't download the file again to check, just made sure the link worked. Have corrected the error now and the right file is there!

Comment: @Raystafarian  Sorry - I uploaded an 'in progress' copy of the workbook in error. The correct one is there now. I'm trying to get DSUM figures for a "YEAR" (variable criteria to check each one manually at A1:A2, currently reads '1996') adding up the values in each of the country code columns in the database (the 'field's, which is where I seem to be experiencing the problems). So, in English rather than Excel, look down 'x' country column, and add up all of the values for '1996'.

Comment: Okay, so you want the `check` sheet to return the number of entries on `data` where `year = 1996` for each value in `row 1`?

Comment: @Raystafarian No, I want the `check` sheet to return the sum of the values in a column - say 'IL' - on `data` where the 'year' column for that row is '1996'. The output for column 'IL' is '58' ... which is correct. If you add up all of the individual values for 'IL' where the year is 1996, it equals '58'. The same should be true for column 'IT', which is the next column along in the `data` sheet, but although the DSUM query is exactly the same except specifying add up the 'IT' column not the 'IL', it starts to error.

Comment: IT and IL have no data for 1996. Perhaps you meant to use 1998? Regardless, the formula I used doesn't error and returns 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come up with this to work

`=DSUM(Data!$A$1:Data!$BT$2000, D$1,$A$1:$A$2)` dragged across row 2 on `check` starting at D2

`=DSUM()` criteria are `=DSUM(database, field, criteria)` where

- database will be where you're searching
- field is the header you're looking for when
- criteria is met

Field can be the column number, or the text you're looking for. In this scenario you're looking to return for each entry on row 1 in `check`, so you can reference row 1 with `D$1` and it will change column, but not row, searching for the text in that cell in the database when the criteria is true.

Comment: Hmmm. Can you feel me going red? The data range has been "...$AR$2000" for so long, I didn't allow for the fact I've inserted new columns. I've been staring at the formula looking for errors in the field or the criteria. 'Word blind' to the actual database range. If you listen carefully in about five minutes time you should hear the sound of me hitting my wrist with a ruler! Thank you for spotting such a fundamental error!

Comment: no worries, it happens.

Answer (score 0):

2 problems I see - One will fix the issue, and one that will save you fixing the formulas as you drag the data down

- You don't search all the data:
  You search A1:AR2000 - Range should be A1:BT2000
  `=DSUM(Data!$A$1:Data!$BT$2000, AA1,$A$1:$A$2)`
- When you copy the formula down, it will change the AA1 to AA2, AA3 etc, when you want it to stay at AA1
  Add a $ in the AA1, in front of the 1 to stop it from changing the row
  `=DSUM(Data!$A$1:Data!$BT$2000, AA$1,$A$1:$A$2)`

Comment: I also see that **RS** have never voted, so you will always get `#VALUE!` for that column

Comment: `MC` `ME` etc and `RS` have no data, I return 0 for 1996

Comment: @Raystafarian - Ok.. Got enthusiastic when changing formula - did a search and replace for AR to BT, and completely forgot it would change the country reference. I'll leave the comment for my **D'oh** moment

Comment: Thanks both. The database is incomplete right now ... 'MC' etc. will have values once they're entered ... I'm planning ahead and the 'check' sheet is there for me to ensure the data I'm entering adds up to what it should. Now that I (you!) have solved the fundamental problem adding multiple check lines to permanently monitor all of the years is easy, especially using `$` to anchor a row and\or column. That should flag if I accidentally overwrite a '1996' entry with '1997' etc.